# Models of extensionality and comprehension without union

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I want to find a model that satisfy comprehension and extensionality axiom but that it does not satisfy union axiom. I think that $M:=\{a,b,c,d,e,g\}$ with $\in^M=\{(a,b),(a,c),(b,e),(c,d),(e,g),(d,g)\}$ is one of such models. It is easy to see that $M\models extensionality$ and $M\nvDash union$, but I can't formalize a proof to show that $M\vDash comprehension$. Can someone give me a hint to complete my task?

Comment: Comprehension? You mean that Fregean axiom which Russell proved to be inconsistent?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not, it is not. I apologize but a don't knew that there is another way to call it. I meant separation axiom.

Comment: Why does your model fail to satisfy union? It seems to me that the union of $a$ is $a$, the union of $b$ is $a$, and the union of $c$ is $b$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I see it, I was think that as the union of $b$ and $c$ does not exists inside $M$ then not satisfy union but, the class $\{a, b\}$ itself does not exists. So, my model is wrong.

Comment: @Gödel Sorry for overlooking that in my answer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I did edit my answer. In this case, am I right?

Comment: @Gödel I don't think that one even satisfies extensionality. I can think of an example with 5 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comprehension (which, as Asaf points out, should be called subset comprehension or separation to distinguish from the inconsistent unrestricted comprehension) is pretty straightforward for finite models, since there’s never any question of the definability of a subset. Furthermore, here, every set has at most one member, so at most two possible subsets, itself and the empty set. We have an empty set in $M$ (the element $a$), and of course the set itself is in $M,$ so we’re done.

Really we should just stare at $$ \forall x,z,\vec w\;\exists y\;\forall x (x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in z \land \phi(x,z,\vec w)).$$ As I mentioned, the “arbitrary formula” part is trivial since we can make it behave however  we want as a function of $x.$

Comment: If I understand you, you says that to prove "comprehension" it is sufficient  that every subset exists ?(In the case of a finite model)

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient, but then again it’s always sufficient. (Really, the important thing with finite models is that it is necessary).

Comment: This point clear to me many things about the theory. It has sense that you say. Thanks